# sql adding a field to a table and updating it with count values from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a *customer* table with 285 407 rows with 285 407 customer_id's as the key. I also have an *account* table with 602 626 rows, this contains 197 010 distinct customer_id's.

I want to append a column to the *customer* table num_accounts that will hold the number of accounts each customer in the *customer* table has, null if they don't have any.

I tried implementing the answer in: [Update count column from data in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701422/update-count-column-from-data-in-another-table) but it takes forever to run, and I'm 90% sure I'm doing something wrong in the joining of *customer* and *account*.

```
alter table customer add num_accounts number;

update customer
set num_accounts = (select count(account_id) from account where account.customer_id = customer.customer_id group by account.customer_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need 100% accurate results, you can consider using materialized views:

create materialized view customer2 as (
select c.customed_id, count(a.account_id) cnt
from customer c, account a
where c.customer_id = a.customer_id
...
group by c.customer_id
);

Then query joining the original customer table and customed2, joining by customer_id.
And refresh the view every night at 2AM.

(http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm)

Another approach may be adding trigger(s) on your account table after insert, delete, update (for each row) and do the count() and update of the customer table in the body of that trigger. This may impact  performance if you change the account table often, and may lead to incorrect results after import/export so you may need to write a procedure to recalculate that from scratch.