# SQL - How to connect an UPDATE with a COUNT-function?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hi I am quite new to SQL and I was trying to search here and on Tutorial sites but somehow can't get to a solution. My problem is actually simple.
I have 3 tables: *tweets*, *users*, *bon_results*.

In order to get my final `.csv-data` I need to add some values into the table 'users'. But those values I need to create via a function first. I need to do the following: Each tweet has a favorite_count. I need to SUM it up and GROUP BY user, like:

`SELECT user, count(favorite_count) FROM tweets GROUP BY user`

The Point is I need to write this into the table 'users' into a column 'favorite_count' and I seriously don't know how to connect these two steps. I tried it via the UPDATE-Statement like this:

```
UPDATE users
SET favorite_count=COUNT(favorite_count) FROM tweets
WHERE tweets.user=users.user
```

I know that the part after the "=" is bullshit but I don't know how to get the function COUNT into this.

Advice would be marvelous.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Here's a similar question that should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10701422/536610

Comment: I use DB Browser for SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always tag the RDBMS you are using in the question.

You can use a Correlated query to the update in most of the databases:

```
update users u 
set favorite_count = (
        select count(favorite_count) 
        from tweets t
        where t.user = u.user
        );
```

If you don't want correlation, the other solutions are mostly vendor specific.

In SQL Server, you can use:

```
update u
set u.favorite_count = t.cnt
from users u join (
    select 
        user, 
        count(favorite_count) as cnt
    FROM tweets 
    GROUP BY user
    ) t on u.user = t.user;
```

In MySQL:

```
update users u join (
    select 
        user, 
        count(favorite_count) as cnt
    FROM tweets 
    GROUP BY user
    ) t on u.user = t.user
set u.favorite_count = t.cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this bro.

```
Update b
    SET  favorite_count=COunt(favorite_count)
    FROM
    tweets  a
    JOIN
    Users b
    ON a.Column1=b.Column1
```

Answer (score 0):

You were really close to the subquery version:

```
update users
  set favorite_count = (
    select count(favorite_count) 
    from tweets 
    where tweets.user=users.user
    );
```

Inner join to a derived table (subquery) version :

```
update u
  set favorite_count = t.favorite_count
from users u
  inner join (
    select user, count(favorite_count) as favorite_count
    from tweets
    group by user
  ) as t
    on u.user = t.user
```